# java apache commons telnet retry failure

Tags: java, telnet, failover

I am using Java 6 and attempting to write a failover for a telnet connection (i.e. if it fails to connect/refused, times out, etc to address1 to failover and try again to address2). If address1 works, then all is good and my result is returned, if however, the first address refuses the connection, address2 will always fail (even if it is set to the working address in the first test). Telnet service is a convenience class that just handles the connection options, and does the "getting" the data from the inputStream (if anyone needs more detail: this is in a GWT server-side service impl class):

I am using commons-net-3.3

here are code section that fails to "failover":

```
public List<Problem> searchForProblemRemote(final String searchStr) {

    String msg = "ProblemService:searchForProblemRemote; searchString = " + searchStr;

    if (!GWT.isProdMode()) {
      log.info(" Remote Address : " + getThreadLocalRequest().getRemoteAddr() + " Session Id: "
          + getThreadLocalRequest().getSession().getId() + " User: "
          + getThreadLocalRequest().getSession().getAttribute("user") + " Info: " + msg);
    }


    List<Problem> clientProblemList = null;// new
    try {
      final TelnetService telnet = new TelnetService();

      // HF - this is now using the imo host address from the config file
      final String imoHostAddress = ConfigurationLoader.getConfiguration().getImoHostAddress();
      final String imoAccountNumber = ConfigurationLoader.getConfiguration().getImoAccountNumber();
      final int imoProblemItPort = ConfigurationLoader.getConfiguration().getImoProblemItPort();

      String searchResults = "";
      // here is where we try the timeout
      try {
        telnet.connect(imoHostAddress, imoProblemItPort);
        searchResults = telnet.getResult("search^50^" + searchStr + "^" + imoAccountNumber);
      } catch (Exception e1) {
        // HF - if we fail to connect try the failover
        final String imoHostFailoverAddress = ConfigurationLoader.getConfiguration().getImoHostFailoverAddress();
        final String imoAccountFailoverNumber = ConfigurationLoader.getConfiguration().getImoAccountFailoverNumber();
        log.fatal("IMO FAILOVER: on " + imoHostAddress + " with " + e1.getLocalizedMessage());

        try {
          telnet.disconnect();

          log.fatal("IMO FAILOVER RECOVERY: on " + imoHostFailoverAddress);
          telnet.connect(imoHostFailoverAddress, imoProblemItPort);
          searchResults = telnet.getResult("search^50^" + searchStr + "^" + imoAccountFailoverNumber);
          log.fatal("IMO FAILOVER SUCCESS: on " + imoHostFailoverAddress);
        } catch (Exception e) {
          log.fatal("IMO FAILOVER RECOVERY FAILED: on " + imoHostFailoverAddress + " with " + e.getLocalizedMessage());
          throw new IOException("IMO SERVER FAILURE: Unable to connect to either primary \"" + imoHostAddress
              + "\" or  failover \"" + imoHostFailoverAddress);
        }
      }

      log.info("IMO Search searchResults, User: " + getThreadLocalRequest().getSession().getAttribute("user")
          + " Results:" + searchResults);
      telnet.disconnect();

    //CODE REMOVED HERE FOR CLARITY (lots of processing of results stuff)
```

Comment: That's a lot of code to put in a catch() - and then a try catch in a catch()? Wild.

Comment: I should add that the second failure is always a "connection refused"